# Which DB should I use on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I would like to use for my app? This app data mostly read (insert about 100 rows every hour, barely edit), so just need search and simple aggregation (grouping) query. I can make this data structure table type, but seems NoSQL is much effect way for search. Isn't it? Which one should use for this app?

- MySQL - common relational database + free tier
- Aurora - better than MySQL(?)
- Elasticsearch - good search performance(?) + free tier
- DynamoDB - not enough query (may not use)

Comment: What is the nature of your query, is it full text, one or two columns or many columns? and how large is your data set and its growth?

Comment: It's about 6 columns and it's 30k data and keep adding 100 rows every hours

Comment: Do you do full text search on the columns?

Comment: not for cilent. it will need for me (which mean it will barely need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirements, it seems like a relational database suits your scenarios. Out of mysql and aurora I would go for aurora since the read throughput is higher compared to mysql. Since the full text search doesn't require to scale based on number of clients (Since only you will be using it), directly searching the database would be reasonable.

The challenge with DynamoDB for your scenario is, you will either need to scan the table to query data from 6 columns or create indexes for them.

Elasticsearch is a good option, but it will require to store the data and use (e.g using RDS or DynamoDB) for durability and use Elasticsearch to index the columns, for full text search.